# Bit definition error - IAR Workbench

Tags: stm32f4, iar

I am a beginner with embedded programming and am using the IAR workbench for a project of mine using `STM32F4Discovery`. I am trying to compile an existing code and have a few errors at  a few places regarding the bit definitions like the following:

`Error[Pe020]: identifier "GPIO_PIN_SET" is undefined`

`Error[Pe020]: identifier "DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler" is undefined`

I have around 100 such errors. The `GPIO_PIN_SET` is defined in the file `stm32f4xx_gpio_hal.h` and is already included in my project. In order to resolve this issue when I looked up online, I have found [this](https://www.electronicsblog.net/start-with-iar-embedded-workbench-for-atmel-avr-attiny13-led-blink-with-timer-interrupt/) solution. However, I don't have the `System`  tab in the `General Options` in my IAR Workbench. I have a full version of IAR Workbench and am not sure why the `System` tab is missing.

I also tried defining

```
#define ENABLE_BIT_DEFINITIONS
```

as stated in [this](http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=25083) link in my `main.c` file but to no avail.

Trying to set

```
#define STM32F4XX
#define USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
```

in the `main.c` file or defining the symbols `STM32F4XX`, `USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER` in the `Preprocessor` tab in `General Options` as mentioned [here](http://dccharacter.blogspot.de/2013/03/creating-new-project-for-stm32f4.html) also didn't help.

The solution could be very simple that I am probably overlooking but am not able to figure out what could I be missing. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you included stm32f4xx.h file into your project? Also visit http://stm32f4-discovery.com/

Comment: Yes, I have @ParadoxECE

Comment: Nobody can help you without your source code.

Comment: I recommend using an "include" XYZ, statement rather than a "define" statement.  You have to include system defined definitions.